# How to make sure Observable stream handles all requests

Tags: rxjs

I am making a simple webserver using RxJS, but I'm not sure how to handle it.

If instead of my first map I use a switchMap, the server would call the handler, which returns an observable. But if another request comes in while the first one is still receiving data, the server would switch to the new request if it finished before the first one, and the first one would simply be dropped, correct?

On the other hand, if I use concatMap, it will call the handler, but it will not consume any more connections until the first one has received all its data and continued on. This doesn't make sense either as the server would idle waiting on slow connections (i.e. POST file uploads) before processing fast ones (i.e. GET requests).

What operator should I use instead?

```
Observable.fromEvent(server, 'request', (req, res) => { return { req: req, res: res } })
    //should this be a concatMap or switchMap or what?
    .map(state => {
        state.data = [];
        return Observable.fromEvent(state.req, 'data')
            .takeUntil(Observable.fromEvent(state.req, 'end'))
            .reduce((n, e) => { n.push(e); return n; }, [])
            .map(e => {
                var buf = Buffer.concat(e).toString('utf8');
                try {
                    state.req.body = JSON.parse(state.data);
                } catch (e) {
                    state.req.body = data;
                }
                return state;
            });
    })
    .do(obs => {
        //I want to do the next thing here, but first I 
        //have to consume the Observable, which doesn't make sense
        state.do(state => {})
    })
```

Comment: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap

Comment: @cartant, if you make that an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll make it an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) is the operator you want.

Unlike `concatMap`, it will not wait for each inner observable to complete before concatenating the next. (In fact, `concatMap` is equivalent to [`mergeMap` with the `concurrency` parameter set to `1`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.2.0/src/operator/concatMap.ts#L71-L74).)